# Flutter Hive with ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod, flutter-hive

So I wanted to use Hive for storing notes in a Calendar app but I am stuggling so much with implementing Hive and a ChangeNotifierProvider together . If anyone has an idea on what to do I would like to see it.

**Here is my code until now :**

```
    @HiveType(typeId: 0)
class EventsBox extends HiveObject {
  EventsBox({required this.date, required this.eventsList});
  @HiveField(0)
  DateTime date;
  @HiveField(1)
  List<CleanCalendarEvent> eventsList;
}
```

**And here is the FutureProvider that is needed :**

```
final hiveProvider = FutureProvider<HiveDB>((_) => HiveDB.create());

class HiveDB {
  var _events;

  HiveDB._create() {}

  static Future<HiveDB> create() async {
    final component = HiveDB._create();
    await component._init();
    return component;
  }

  _init() async {
    Hive.registerAdapter(EventsBoxAdapter());
    this._events = await Hive.openBox<EventsBox>('events');
  }

  storeEvent(EventsBox eventsMap) {
    this._events.put('events', eventsMap);
  }

  EventsBox getEvents() {
    return this._events.get('events');
  }
}
```

**I want to use ChangeNotifierProvider and not FutureProvider**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of the provider framework is to inject dependencies into your app without recreating them all the time. In your example, you have your `HiveDB` class which is what you want to inject into your app for various other widgets to use it.

IMO, the general approach of "providing" dependencies is:

1. Create dependency instances outside the app (Typically in the `main()` function)
2. Create a provider which injects this dependency object
3. Wrap your `MaterialApp` with the provider
4. Supply your dependency object into the provider wrapper
5. Use the `Provider<DependencyClass>.of(context)` to access your dependency wherever you need it in your app.

---

Let's see how this applies to your code:

#### 1. Setup your Hive models and HiveDB

`lib/models/event_box.dart`

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class EventsBox extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  DateTime date;

  @HiveField(1)
  List<CleanCalendarEvent> eventsList;

  EventsBox({
    required this.date, 
    required this.eventsList,
  });
}
```

`lib/models/hive_db.dart`

```dart
class HiveDB {
  var _events;

  HiveDB._create() {}

  static Future<HiveDB> create() async {
    final component = HiveDB._create();
    await component._init();
    return component;
  }

  _init() async {
    Hive.registerAdapter(EventsBoxAdapter());
    this._events = await Hive.openBox<EventsBox>('events');
  }

  storeEvent(EventsBox eventsMap) {
    this._events.put('events', eventsMap);
  }

  EventsBox getEvents() {
    return this._events.get('events');
  }
}
```

> In this case, you want to "provide" (or inject) an instance of `HiveDB` to your app.

#### 2. Create a provider for your `HiveDB` instance

`lib/models/hive_db_provider.dart`

```dart
class HiveDbProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  final HiveDB db;
  final Widget child;

  const HiveDbProvider({
    Key? key,
    required this.db,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<HiveDB>.value(
      value: db,
      child: Consumer<AppCache>(
        builder: (context, db, _) {
          return child;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 3. Create HiveDB instance in `main()`

`lib/main.dart`

```dart
void main() async {
  final HiveDB db = await HiveDB.create();

  runApp(
    MyApp(db: db)
  );
}

...
```

#### 4. Inject the HiveDB instance using the provider

`lib/main.dart`

```dart
...

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final HiveDB db;

  const PayBuddy({
    Key? key,
    required this.db,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HiveDbProvider(
      db: db,
      child: CacheProvider(
        cache: cache,
        child: MaterialApp(
          ...
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 5. Access "provided" instance using `Provider` anywhere in your app

`lib/pages/some_screen.dart`

```dart
import "package:provider/provider.dart";
...

class SomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Access HiveDB instance
    final hiveDb = Provider<HiveDB>.of(context);

    ...
  }
}
```

---

#### Conclusion

The sample uses the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) which simplifies using provider usage in Flutter.

Comment: Thank you for your answear . Although i doesnt cover 100% of what I wanted , the idea is now planted in my head and I will figure it out